# Searching multiple strings in one txt file

Tags: php, html

I do know there are multiple other answers to this, but they do not fit on the code I have. Since the code I have has to handle 1000 lines + per search.

I want to combine the strings of 2 inputs so the PHP script searches for both in the txt files and combines them when outputting.

This is what I tried:

```
$search = $_GET["search"]; 
$search2 = $_GET['search2'];
$logfile = $_GET['logfile'];


// Read from file 
$file = fopen($logfile, "r");?> 
<head><title>Searching: <?php echo $search ?></title></head>
<?php
while( ($line =  fgets($file) && $line2 = fgets($file))!= false)
{   if (stristr($line, $search)) { } if (stristr($line2, $search2)) { }  

?><font face='Arial'> <?php $lines = $line + line2; ?><?php echo $lines ?></font><hr><p><?php
}
```

When I run this code with both search and search2 filled in: I get this output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

And those 1's seem to be infinite.
I hope anyone has a solution.

The outputs should be for both strings:
search = 'new'

```
He is a new player
Gambling is a new sport
New is better than old
```

search2 = 'website'

```
It is a nice website
The website is down
The FIFA website is being built
```

The right output should be:

```
He is a new player
It is a nice website
Gambling is a new sport
The FIFA website is being built
New is better than old
```

Thank you for reading.

~Conner

Comment: Could you give some examples of what output you expect and which input/parameters should generate that output?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you have two `fgets()` reading into two different variables? And why not do one regex search like `(new|website)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
$search1 = "value 1"; 
$search2 = "value 2";

$lines = file('my_file.txt'); 

foreach($lines as $line) 
{ 
    if(stristr($line,$search1) || stristr($line,$search2))

        echo " $line <br>"; 
} 
?>
```

Please see if this code works.
This will give you the lines where `$search1` **or** `$search2` appear. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach (new SplFileObject($logfile) as $lineNumber => $lineContent) {
    if(strpos($lineContent, $search) !== false
       || strpos($lineContent, $search2) !== false
    ) {
        echo $lineContent . '<br />';
    }
}
```